# AWS ResetException - Failed to reset the request input stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, inputstream, aws-sdk

I'm currently working on some code that uploads multi-part objects to S3, and I am running into this error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.ResetException: Failed to reset the request input stream;  If the request involves an input stream, the maximum stream buffer size can be configured via request.getRequestClientOptions().setReadLimit(int)
```

Originally the readLimit was set to 5MB. I had changed the code so that the ReadLimit on the input stream would be the Object Size rounded up to the nearest 5MB (With a 5GB cap since thats the AWS limit). This seemed to fix the issue but now the same error is showing up in new places.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what value to set the readLimit at for the most reliability?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Ted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those looking for an answer, the solution is to use a RetryPolicy with a BackOffStrategy. A backoffstrategy slowly increases the amount of time inbetween connection attempts.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html

Furthermore, if you use a backoffstrategy you need to use a compatible FileStreamer which can Mark/Reset when uploading data.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-java-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/best-practices.rst